# Confusing behavior from xargs when used with the adb shell

Tags: linux, grep, xargs

I'm confused about the following xargs behavior.

### 1 This command works.

```
$ adb shell 'find /system/etc/permissions/ | xargs grep gid=\"system\"'
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.location.xml:    <group gid="system" />
/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml:        <group gid="system"/>
/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml:        <group gid="system"/>
```

### 2 This command also works.

```
$ adb shell 'grep -B 4 gid=\"system\" /system/etc/permissions/*'
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.location.xml-<permission name="com.qualcomm.permission.IZAT" >
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.location.xml-    <group gid="gps" />
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.location.xml-    <group gid="net_raw" />
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.location.xml-    <group gid="net_admin" />
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.location.xml:    <group gid="system" />
-- snip -- snip --
```

### 3 This command does NOT work.

```
$ adb shell 'find /system/etc/permissions/ | xargs grep -C 4 gid=\"system\"'
usage: grep [-EFivwcloqsHbhn] [-m MAX] [-e REGEX]... [-f REGFILE] [FILE]...
-- snip -- snip --
grep: Unknown option C
```

### 4 Additional info.

```
$ adb shell 'grep'
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
[-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
[--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
[pattern] [file ...]
```

- Question-1: Why doesn't the #3 command work? What am I missing? Perhaps I don't understand xargs behavior.
- Question-2: According to the usage outputs, are there two grep commands? Which one is the #3 grep, used with xargs?

Thanks in advance.

### Update:

Question-1 is solved. To use `/system/bin/grep` instead of `grep` can work. But I still don't know where the #3 grep come from.

Answer (score 3):

Look carefully at

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
```

It looks like `-C` does not allow a blank, unlike `-A` and `-B`. Try

```
adb shell 'find /system/etc/permissions/ | xargs grep -C4 gid=\"system\"'
```

to test this hypothesis. If this does not fix it, try using `--context=4` instead of `-C 4`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also editing my poor English. Unfortunately, both `-C4` and `--context=4` doesn't work. The #3 error messages are still shown.

Answer (score 1):

adb shell 'find /system/etc/permissions/ | xargs grep -C4 gid="system"'
Here look you have enclosed entire command with quote and sended to adbshell and thus it uses xargs installed on your android which is extremely limited in options.

other commands worked because they uses xargs installed on windows machine/ linux machine which has more features